# How to get a single attribute from $_POST['Tblmodel']

Tags: yii

Normally,

```
 $model->attributes=$_POST['Tblmodel'];
```

assigns all the attributes value from `$_POST['Tblmodel']` to `$model`.

I want only to get one attributes value from `$_POST['Tblmodel']`.

For example:

I only want the value of 'id'. I was trying like this `$_POST['Tblmodel']-> id` and this doesn't work.

How can i get it?

Comment: Have you tried this `$_POST['Tblmodel']['id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
$_POST['Tblmodel']['id'];
```

instead of

```
$_POST['Tblmodel']-> id
```

Comment: This wont work as $_POST['Tblmodel'] is not an object. It is an array.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Tblmodel'];
$model->id;
```

Or use

```
$_POST['Tblmodel']['id'];
```

Comment: I know this; but i cant perform it in my situation;cause before assigning to $model i need the id.